# Add background image to select option element

Tags: jquery

I need to add a background image to select option elements using Jquery. I tried with this CSS and HTML (but not working at all).

I need to do this using Jquery. It is a Wordpress site.

```css
.my_select_class option[value="blue_car"] {
  background-image: url('blueCar.jpg');
}
```

```html
<select class="my_select_class">
  <option value="blue_car">Blue Car</option>
  <option value="red_car">Red Car</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You cannot reliably style `option` elements like this. If you need this behaviour you will need to use a library which converts a `select` to HTML elements which can be styled however you require. I'd suggest Select2.

Comment: You can do this using jQuery by adding this to your options `data-color="#hexcolor"` and then in your JavaScript add this: `$("select").change(function () {
  $(this).css("background", $(this).children("option:selected").data("color"));
});`

Comment: @HaldenCollier I am afraid I don't get you. Could you please elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Wish I could but this question has been closed! :(

Comment: Look here: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/IIqqhyVxmivN51gb

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. :)